# How to add the column 'Details' to OGV after piping to another cmdlets

Tags: powershell

I am working on the below script, and would like the output to be combined into one single OGV or `Format-Table -Autosize`.

**Script 1:**

```
$paramGetMessageTrace = @{
   SenderAddress    = 'system@netsuite.com'
   StartDate        = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)
   EndDate           = (Get-Date)
}

Get-MessageTrace @paramGetMessageTrace |
    Where-Object { $_.Status -ne 'Delivered' } |
    Select-Object Received, RecipientAddress, Status, @{n="Detail";e={($_ | Get-MessageTraceDetail | Where-Object {$_.Events -eq 'Fail'} ).Detail}} | ft -AutoSize
```

**Script 1 unexpected result on Console: the Detail column is empty:**

```
Received               RecipientAddress             Status        Detail
--------               ----------------             ------        ------
20/04/2021 11:50:10 PM mosfet@bregen.co.uk          Failed              
20/04/2021 11:46:28 PM whibley.derrick@sum41.net    Failed              
20/04/2021 11:43:03 PM CEO@conrad.co.uk      GettingStatus       
20/04/2021 11:32:55 PM richdad.co.uk                Failed
```

**Script 2:**

```
$paramGetMessageTrace = @{
   SenderAddress    = 'system@netsuite.com'
   StartDate        = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)
   EndDate           = (Get-Date)
}

Get-MessageTrace @paramGetMessageTrace |
    Where-Object { $_.Status -ne 'Delivered' } | Get-MessageTraceDetail
```

**Script 2 unexpected result on Console: the column is empty:**

```
Date                   Event                Detail
----                   -----                ------
20/04/2021 11:50:11 PM Receive              Message received by: BLCPR01MB5197.prod.outlook.com
20/04/2021 11:50:44 PM Fail                 Reason: [{LED=550 permanent failure for one or more recipients (mosfet@bregen.co.uk:550 5.4.1 All recipient addresses rejected : Access denied. AS(201806271)
20/04/2021 11:46:29 PM Receive              Message received by: BL3PR01MB1481.prod.outlook.com
20/04/2021 11:46:35 PM Fail                 Reason: [{LED=550 5.1.1 User Unknown};{MSG=};{FQDN=mxb-0036d701.gslb.pphosted.com};{LRT=4/20/2021 11:46:30 PM}].
20/04/2021 11:43:04 PM Receive              Message received by: BLCPR01MB4078.prod.outlook.com
20/04/2021 11:43:07 PM Send external        Message sent to mail.conrad.co.uk at 134.47.61.32 using TLS1.2 with AES256
20/04/2021 11:32:55 PM Receive              Message received by: MEXPR01MB1176.prod.outlook.com
20/04/2021 11:32:57 PM Fail                 Reason: [{LED=550 5.4.310 DNS domain richdad.co.uk does not exist [Message=InfoDomainNonexistent] [LastAttemptedServerName=richdad.co.uk]
```

This is the script that I have come up with, but the result is still the same, empty Detail column:

```
Get-MessageTrace @paramGetMessageTrace |
  Where-Object { $_.Status -ne 'Delivered' } | Select-Object * | Get-MessageTraceDetail | Select-Object * | ogv
```

[image]

Even using the required parameters but still not showing the detailed column:

```
$paramGetMessageTrace = @{
  SenderAddress    = 'system@netsuite.com'
  StartDate        = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)
  EndDate           = (Get-Date)
}


Get-MessageTrace @paramGetMessageTrace |
  Where-Object { $_.Status -ne 'Delivered' } |
  Select-Object Received, RecipientAddress, Status, `
    @{n="Detail"; e={Get-MessageTraceDetail -MessageTraceID   $_.MessageTraceID `
                                            -RecipientAddress $_.RecipientAddress `
                                            -Event Fail |
                       Select -Expand Detail}} |
  ft -AutoSize
```

Updated Script as suggested by @Theo:

```
Get-MessageTrace @paramGetMessageTrace | Where-Object { $_.Status -ne 'Delivered' } | 
        Get-MessageTraceDetail | Where-Object {$_.Event -eq 'Fail'} | 
            ft -AutoSize
```

The result is almost correct, I just need to show the Recipient email address column:

```
Date                   Event Detail                                                                                                                           
----                   ----- ------                                                                                                                           
20/04/2021 11:50:44 PM Fail  Reason: [{LED=550 permanent failure for one or more recipients (.....u:550 5.4.1 All recipient addresses reject...
20/04/2021 11:46:35 PM Fail  Reason: [{LED=550 5.1.1 User Unknown};{MSG=};{FQDN=mxb-0036d701.gslb.pphosted.com};{IP=185.183.28.184};{LRT=4/20/2021 11:46:30...
20/04/2021 11:32:57 PM Fail  Reason: [{LED=550 5.4.310 DNS domain richdad.co.uk does not exist [Message=InfoDomainNonexistent] [LastAttemptedServerNam...
```

Appendix:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-messagetrace?view=exchange-ps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-messagetracedetail?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Looking at the output from script #2, Shouldn't this part of script #1 `Where-Object {$_.Events -eq 'Fail'}` be `Where-Object {$_.Event -eq 'Fail'}` ? (singular)

Comment: Many thanks @Theo, the updated script you've suggested, somehow does not show the RecipientAddress ?